# Unable to publish taxonomies

Tags: content-delivery, taxonomy

We are running SDL Tridion 2011 SP1_HR1 with Oracle 11g R2 as the CMS and Broker database. Recently users (content editors) are unable to publish Taxonomies. The storage config is configured to store taxonomies to the database and publishing taxonomies was working fine until a couple of days ago. When trying to publish taxonomies the publish transaction gets stuck at "Committing Deployment" whereas we are successfully able to publish other items (like components, pages etc.).

The transaction ID in this example is: **tcm:0-628531-66560**

Below is an excerpt from the deployer.log file:

```
2013-06-03 16:15:05,674 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - Retrieving list of files from location: D:\tridion\incoming\staging with extension.Content.zip 
2013-06-03 16:15:05,690 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - Found 3 files in folder D:\tridion\incoming\staging
2013-06-03 16:15:05,815 INFO  HTTPSReceiverServlet - Persisting received TransportPackage: tcm_0-628531-66560.Content.zip
2013-06-03 16:15:06,487 TRACE DeployPackage - Package type: Content
2013-06-03 16:15:06,487 TRACE DeployPackage - Transaction Part of package: tcm_0-628531-66560
2013-06-03 16:15:06,487 TRACE DeployPackage - TransactionId: 628531
2013-06-03 16:15:06,487 TRACE ContentLocationHandler - No existing progress file, accepting package for processing: tcm:0-628531-66560.
2013-06-03 16:15:06,487 INFO  ContentLocationHandler - Found 1 new packages for processing in D:\tridion\incoming\staging
2013-06-03 16:15:06,487 INFO  QueueLocationHandler - Retrieved Deployment package from queue with transactionId: tcm:0-628531-66560 and type: CONTENT
2013-06-03 16:15:06,487 TRACE QueueLocationHandler - Current number of tasks in queue: 0 for type: CONTENT
2013-06-03 16:15:06,487 INFO  QueueLocationHandler - Starting running transaction thread: tcm:0-628531-66560
2013-06-03 16:15:06,487 TRACE QueueLocationHandler - Checking for lockfile: D:\tridion\incoming\staging\tcm_0-628531-66560_content.progress.
2013-06-03 16:15:06,502 DEBUG QueueLocationHandler - Exclusive lock on Deployment package acquired for transaction tcm:0-628531-66560
2013-06-03 16:15:06,502 INFO  TransactionManager - Starting handling of Deployment package: tcm:0-628531-66560 with type: CONTENT
2013-06-03 16:15:06,924 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Starting executing deployment pipeline for: tcm:0-628531-66560
2013-06-03 16:15:06,924 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Executing deployment phase: Deployer Prepare Phase for transaction: tcm:0-628531-66560
2013-06-03 16:15:06,924 DEBUG UnzipWorker - zipLocation = D:\tridion\incoming\staging\tcm_0-628531-66560.Content.zip
2013-06-03 16:15:06,924 INFO  UnzipWorker - Starting unzipping for transaction: tcm:0-628531-66560 and package: D:\tridion\incoming\staging\tcm_0-628531-66560.Content.zip
2013-06-03 16:15:06,940 INFO  UnzipWorker - Moving Deployment Package to unzip folder for transactionId: tcm:0-628531-66560
2013-06-03 16:15:06,955 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Executing deployment phase: Deployment Processing Phase for transaction: tcm:0-628531-66560
2013-06-03 16:15:07,049 INFO  ProcessingPhase - Starting executing of phase: PRE_PROCESSING for transaction: tcm:0-628531-66560
2013-06-03 16:15:07,065 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Starting processors for phase: pre-processing
2013-06-03 16:15:07,065 INFO  ProcessorFactory - Creating processors for phase: pre-processing
2013-06-03 16:15:07,065 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Processors finished for phase: pre-processing
2013-06-03 16:15:07,065 INFO  ProcessingPhase - Starting executing of phase: PROCESSING for transaction: tcm:0-628531-66560
2013-06-03 16:15:07,065 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Starting processors for phase: processing
2013-06-03 16:15:07,065 INFO  ProcessorFactory - Creating processors for phase: processing
2013-06-03 16:15:07,065 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.deployer.modules.SchemaDeploy
2013-06-03 16:15:07,080 DEBUG TCDLEngine - TCDL: Using built-in tag registry
2013-06-03 16:15:07,096 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.deployer.modules.BinaryDeploy
2013-06-03 16:15:07,112 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentDeploy
2013-06-03 16:15:07,112 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.deployer.modules.TemplateDeploy
2013-06-03 16:15:07,112 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.deployer.modules.PublicationDeploy
2013-06-03 16:15:07,112 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.deployer.modules.TaxonomyDeploy
2013-06-03 16:15:07,112 DEBUG TCDLEngine - TCDL: Using built-in tag registry
2013-06-03 16:15:07,127 INFO  Module - No TransformProcessor configured, will not transform files before deployment for module com.tridion.deployer.modules.StructureGroupDeploy
2013-06-03 16:15:07,127 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Starting processor with action: Deploy in phase: processing for transaction: tcm:0-628531-66560
2013-06-03 16:15:07,127 INFO  Processor - Modules will now process package [TransportPackage transactionId=tcm:0-628531-66560]
2013-06-03 16:15:07,127 DEBUG SchemaDeploy - Processing section Schemas
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 DEBUG DeploymentHandler - Deploying tcd:pub[0]/pub[10].
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: Page with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.pages.FSPageHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: Page with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.pages.SQLPageHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: Page with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.pages.Oracle9PageHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: PageMeta with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.pages.meta.SQLPageMetaHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: PageMeta with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.pages.meta.XMLFilePageMetaHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: Binary with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.binaries.FSBinaryHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: Binary with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.binaries.Oracle9BinaryHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: Binary with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.binaries.SQLBinaryHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: BinaryMeta with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.binaries.meta.SQLBinaryMetaHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: BinaryMeta with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.binaries.meta.XMLFileBinaryMetaHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: TextComponentPresentation with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.FSTextComponentPresentationHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: TextComponentPresentation with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.MsSqlTextComponentPresentationHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: TextComponentPresentation with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.DB2TextComponentPresentationHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: TextComponentPresentation with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.OracleTextComponentPresentationHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: ASPComponentPresentation with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.FSASPComponentPresentationHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: ASPComponentPresentation with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.FSASCXComponentPresentationHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: ASPComponentPresentation with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.MsSqlASPComponentPresentationHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: ASPComponentPresentation with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.MsSqlASCXComponentPresentationHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: ASPComponentPresentation with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.DB2ASPComponentPresentationHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: ASPComponentPresentation with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.DB2ASCXComponentPresentationHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: ASPComponentPresentation with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.OracleASPComponentPresentationHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: ASPComponentPresentation with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.OracleASCXComponentPresentationHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: JSPComponentPresentation with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.FSJSPComponentPresentationHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: JSPComponentPresentation with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.MsSqlJSPComponentPresentationHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: JSPComponentPresentation with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.DB2JSPComponentPresentationHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: JSPComponentPresentation with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.OracleJSPComponentPresentationHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: XMLComponentPresentation with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.FSXMLComponentPresentationHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: XMLComponentPresentation with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.MsSqlXMLComponentPresentationHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: XMLComponentPresentation with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.DB2XMLComponentPresentationHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: XMLComponentPresentation with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.OracleXMLComponentPresentationHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: ComponentPresentationMeta with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.meta.SQLComponentPresentationMetaHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: ComponentPresentationMeta with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.componentpresentations.meta.XMLFileComponentPresentationMetaHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: ComponentMeta with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.components.meta.XMLFileComponentMetaHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: ComponentMeta with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.components.meta.DB2ComponentMetaHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: ComponentMeta with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.components.meta.MsSqlComponentMetaHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - Registering binding: ComponentMeta with known legacy class: com.tridion.broker.components.meta.OracleComponentMetaHome
2013-06-03 16:15:07,174 DEBUG HandlerFactory - Retrieving typeHandler for itemURI: tcd:pub[0]/pub[10]
2013-06-03 16:15:07,174 TRACE HandlerFactory - The binding for tcd:pub[0]/pub[10] is not supported for custom legacy implementation, skipping further legacy checks
2013-06-03 16:15:07,174 DEBUG TaxonomyDeploy - Processing section Taxonomies
2013-06-03 16:15:07,174 DEBUG TaxonomyDeploy - Schema present for Taxonomy, loading schema information: tcm:10-11718-8
2013-06-03 16:15:09,143 INFO  TaxonomyDeploy - Finished transformation of RDF
2013-06-03 16:15:09,143 DEBUG DeploymentHandler - Deploying tcd:pub[10]/taxonomy[1741].
2013-06-03 16:15:09,143 DEBUG HandlerFactory - Retrieving typeHandler for itemURI: tcd:pub[10]/taxonomy[1741]
2013-06-03 16:15:09,143 TRACE HandlerFactory - The binding for tcd:pub[10]/taxonomy[1741] is not supported for custom legacy implementation, skipping further legacy checks
2013-06-03 16:15:09,143 INFO  Processor - All modules successfully processed package [TransportPackage transactionId=tcm:0-628531-66560]
2013-06-03 16:15:09,143 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Processors finished for phase: processing
2013-06-03 16:15:09,143 INFO  ProcessingPhase - Starting executing of phase: POST_PROCESSING for transaction: tcm:0-628531-66560
2013-06-03 16:15:09,143 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Starting processors for phase: post-processing
2013-06-03 16:15:09,143 INFO  ProcessorFactory - Creating processors for phase: post-processing
2013-06-03 16:15:09,143 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Processors finished for phase: post-processing
2013-06-03 16:15:09,143 INFO  ProcessingPhase - We have 2 transaction items waiting for commit.
2013-06-03 16:15:09,143 INFO  ProcessingPhase - Persisting transaction log for transaction: tcm:0-628531-66560.
2013-06-03 16:15:09,159 INFO  TransactionPersistence - Persisting deployment transaction information: tcm:0-628531-66560
2013-06-03 16:15:09,455 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Executing deployment phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase for transaction: tcm:0-628531-66560
2013-06-03 16:15:09,455 INFO  PreCommitPhase - Executing phase: pre-transaction for transaction: tcm:0-628531-66560
2013-06-03 16:15:09,455 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Starting processors for phase: pre-transaction
2013-06-03 16:15:09,455 INFO  ProcessorFactory - Creating processors for phase: pre-transaction
2013-06-03 16:15:09,455 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Processors finished for phase: pre-transaction
2013-06-03 16:15:09,455 INFO  TransactionPersistence - Loading deployment transaction information: tcm:0-628531-66560
2013-06-03 16:15:09,471 INFO  PreCommitPhase - Executing workers for transaction: tcm:0-628531-66560 with 2 Workers
2013-06-03 16:15:09,471 DEBUG PreCommitPhase - Executing worker com.tridion.storage.deploy.workers.PublicationWorker@54d81cda this is worker 1 of: 2
2013-06-03 16:15:09,862 DEBUG PreCommitPhase - Executing worker: com.tridion.storage.deploy.workers.PublicationWorker@54d81cda took: 391
2013-06-03 16:15:09,862 DEBUG PreCommitPhase - Executing worker com.tridion.storage.deploy.workers.TaxonomyWorker@9c304c7 this is worker 2 of: 2
2013-06-03 16:15:09,987 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - transactionid parameter did not contain a TCM URI string: meta.xml processing as normal file request
2013-06-03 16:15:09,987 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - File found at D:\tridion\incoming\staging\meta.xml for meta.xml
2013-06-03 16:15:15,237 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - transactionid parameter did not contain a TCM URI string: meta.xml processing as normal file request
2013-06-03 16:15:15,237 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - File found at D:\tridion\incoming\staging\meta.xml for meta.xml
2013-06-03 16:15:23,237 DEBUG PreCommitPhase - Executing worker: com.tridion.storage.deploy.workers.TaxonomyWorker@9c304c7 took: 13375
2013-06-03 16:15:23,252 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Executing deployment phase: Deployment Commit Phase for transaction: tcm:0-628531-66560
2013-06-03 16:15:23,252 INFO  CommitPhase - Committing transaction: tcm:0-628531-66560
2013-06-03 16:15:24,127 INFO  TransactionPersistence - Removing deployment transaction information: tcm:0-628531-66560
2013-06-03 16:15:24,127 INFO  CommitPhase - Executing phase: post-transaction for transaction: tcm:0-628531-66560
2013-06-03 16:15:24,127 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Starting processors for phase: post-transaction
2013-06-03 16:15:24,127 INFO  ProcessorFactory - Creating processors for phase: post-transaction
2013-06-03 16:15:24,127 DEBUG ProcessorWorker - Processors finished for phase: post-transaction
2013-06-03 16:15:24,127 DEBUG DeployPipelineExecutor - Checking if transaction is completed: tcm:0-628531-66560 is true
2013-06-03 16:15:24,127 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Transaction is completed: tcm:0-628531-66560
2013-06-03 16:15:24,127 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Finished executing deployment pipeline for: tcm:0-628531-66560 in 17203 ms.
2013-06-03 16:15:24,127 INFO  TransactionManager - Cleaning up Deployment package for transaction: tcm:0-628531-66560 and type: CONTENT
2013-06-03 16:15:24,127 INFO  TransactionManager - Finished handling of Deployment package: tcm:0-628531-66560 with type: CONTENT
2013-06-03 16:15:24,127 DEBUG QueueLocationHandler - Removing exclusive lock on Deployment package: tcm:0-628531-66560 with type: CONTENT.
2013-06-03 16:15:25,455 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - transactionid parameter did not contain a TCM URI string: meta.xml processing as normal file request
2013-06-03 16:15:25,455 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - File found at D:\tridion\incoming\staging\meta.xml for meta.xml
2013-06-03 16:15:25,502 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - transactionid parameter did not contain a TCM URI string: tcm_0-628531-66560.state.xml processing as normal file request
2013-06-03 16:15:25,502 DEBUG HTTPSReceiverServlet - File found at D:\tridion\incoming\staging\tcm_0-628531-66560.state.xml for tcm_0-628531-66560.state.xml
2013-06-03 16:15:25,502 INFO  HTTPSReceiverServlet - Removed file at D:\tridion\incoming\staging\tcm_0-628531-66560.state.xml
```

Comment: There are no errors in your log snippet, and it looks like everything is successfully processed.  After some time, could be several hours, the "Committing Deployment" status should change to an error, which may give another hint.

Comment: Just a wide guess, but you wouldn't happen to have 2 deployer instances running on the same incoming folder?

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible your cd_licenses.xml file has expired, and all your content is being published to your File System rather than the database?

Answer (score 3):

Is there any other item which is configured to saved in DB, If that is also not getting saved in DB, then Chris could be right.

In case of items are configured to be saved to disk, this error occurs when deployer unable to delete the existing item(due to used by some process) and replace with new items.

In your case check, Is there any db locking happening.

Answer (score 1):

Finally narrowed the problem to some Event System code that was triggered upon Publish Success. In case of taxonomies it was throwing an exception and thus the status was never update on the CMS. Thank you everyone for taking the time to help.